# Fresh pasta noodles in lasagna

Tags: pasta, noodles, lasagna

When making lasagna noodles from scratch, do you need to cook the noodles first? If I was making it the regular way, layers, I wouldn't think it would need to be cooked. But I'm rolling the noodles around the cheese mixture and so I was wondering if that was going to make a difference.

Comment: Do you mean [cannelloni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannelloni)?

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/can-fresh-unboiled-egg-pasta-be-used-for-lasagna

Answer (score 1):

Whether the pasta is rolled for [cannelloni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannelloni) or flat for [lasagne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasagne) won't make a difference, just make sure that the tops of the rolls are covered with sauce, too, or they will dry out and taste not nice.

For the pros and cons of fresh vs. dried pasta in "al forno" dishes, see the almost duplicate [lasagne Q/A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/can-fresh-unboiled-egg-pasta-be-used-for-lasagna).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give a different answer than the one I gave in the question that Stephie referenced:

Yes, you (most likely) need to cook the fresh pasta.

The problem is that for the other case to work, you need to at the very least dry the pasta first before you use it.  If you don't, the moisture will just turn the pasta into paste.  For typical lasagne, you're working with flat noodles, so you can get away with it (if you're also using hot sauce, so the noodles cook quickly after being laid out).

As you're going to be rolling the pasta around the filling, you're going to need the pasta to be flexible -- that either means cooked or before it's been dried.

If you *really* want to try making them from just-having-been-rolled-out state, I would make sure that I had my sauce as close to boiling as I could get it (without letting it get to that spatter-all-over-the-place stage), and immediately after wrapping the bundles get them smothered in the hot sauce.  This might allow them to cook fast enough before they turn into cheese + paste.